# How to get values from variable in a private sub or make public variable that does not lose value

Tags: vb.net

I am planning to create a project in the near future about quizzes and now I am practising some codes and this is my problem. I have a variable inside a `private sub Button_Click`. All variables work fine but I can't access it in other `Private sub Button3_Click` because it was a private variable so I decided it to make them a public variable.

Then when I ran it, it's only shows the last item on my database and I get back my original code and all the data in the database are shown and I create an event from my radiobutton when I checked it's automatically INSERT a data into my table. So I need the variable label but I can't access it in my event.

Note: All my controls are add programmatically when the database has a data except for panel1, button2 and button3.

This is my original code:

```
'This is for adding controls like labels and radiobutton dependeng in a number of data from database
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
      Try
        Dim conn As OleDbConnection = GetDBConnection()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblEcobags ORDER BY N ASC", conn)
        cmd.Prepare()
        Dim dataReader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Do While dataReader.Read
            Dim Cpanel As New Panel()
            Dim count As Integer = Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)().ToList().Count
            count = Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)().ToList().Count
            Cpanel.Location = New Point(10, (25 * count) * 2.2)
            Cpanel.Size = New Size(537, 51)
            Cpanel.Name = "Cpanel" & (count + 1)
            Cpanel.BackColor = Color.White
            Panel1.Controls.Add(Cpanel)


            Dim label As New Label()
            count = Cpanel.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().ToList().Count
            label.Location = New Point(10, (25 * count))
            label.AutoSize = True
            label.Name = "label_" & (count + 1)
            label.Text = dataReader.Item("N") & "."
            label.Font = New Font(label.Font.FontFamily, 10, FontStyle.Bold)
            Cpanel.Controls.Add(label)

            Dim lblQ As New Label()
            count = Cpanel.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToList().Count
            lblQ.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(40, 25 * count)
            lblQ.AutoSize = True
            lblQ.Name = "lblQ" & (count + 1)
            lblQ.Text = dataReader.Item("ProductDes")
            lblQ.Font = New Font(lblQ.Font.FontFamily, 11)
            Cpanel.Controls.Add(lblQ)

            Dim rbChoiceA As New RadioButton()
            count = Cpanel.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().ToList().Count
            rbChoiceA.Location = New Point(40, 25)
            rbChoiceA.AutoSize = True
            rbChoiceA.Name = "rb" & (count + 1)
            rbChoiceA.Text = dataReader.Item("Each")
            rbChoiceA.Font = New Font(rbChoiceA.Font.FontFamily, 10)
            AddHandler rbChoiceA.CheckedChanged, AddressOf rbChoiceA_Checked
            Cpanel.Controls.Add(rbChoiceA)

            Dim rbChoiceB As New RadioButton()
            count = Cpanel.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().ToList().Count
            rbChoiceB.Location = New Point(200, 25)
            rbChoiceB.AutoSize = True
            rbChoiceB.Name = "rb" & (count + 1)
            rbChoiceB.Text = dataReader.Item("PerDozen")
            rbChoiceB.Font = New Font(rbChoiceB.Font.FontFamily, 10)
            Cpanel.Controls.Add(rbChoiceB)


        Loop
        Button2.Enabled = False
        conn.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
'this is an event that i can't access my "label" that I add programmatically
Private Sub rbChoiceA_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
 Try
        Dim conn As OleDbConnection = GetDBConnection()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblSubmit(N)VALUES('" & must be label.text & "') ", conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set Variable as static in database or Text file or SQL or in program 
like `string myvar = "static";`

Comment: what programming syntax is that? C# ? I am using vb.net

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad description but I got it worked now. I used to declare it outside from any function but my mistakes that I made is declaring variable with parenthesis, I don't know the difference between that so I need to know the one without parenthesis works.
This is my modified declaration so It must be accessible to any function

```
Dim label as Label()
```

I got error on my updating code inside an event for my button2_Click

```
label = new label() ' I got error here
```

But when I removed the parenthesis on my declaration, it works.

```
Dim label as label
```

so may I ask what's the difference between that, why the one I used is no work than below that was worked. Thanks in advance for the respose.

Comment: `Dim label As Label()` - declare array of type `Label`. Parenthesis with `new` keyword `label = new Label()` - is creation of new instance of type `Label`

Comment: Thank you for that. Now I know.